# Executing animation When an Animation Ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, rotation, jquery-animate

i created a swimming fish and i want in the end of the animation the fish will rotate
and swim to top

```
function anim() {
    $(".fish_wrap").animate({
        "left": "-90px" }, 5000);    
}
anim();
```

here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/TxC5y/3/

Answer (score 2):

[The `.animate()` function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) provides a callback function to be executed when the animation completes.  Something like this:

```
$(".fish_wrap").animate({
    "left": "-90px" }, 5000,
    function () {
        // perform your next task here
});
```

That inline function being passed to `.animate()` will be called when the animation completes, so that's where you'd put your next step(s).  (Rotating and swimming to the top.)